# Search of synonyms of keywords

Tags: python, nlp, synonym, language-detection

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
from langdetect import detect



df1=pd.read_csv('TFG1.csv', encoding = 'utf8')

def find_all_words(words, sentence):
    all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
    words_found = []
    for word in words:

        if word in all_words:
            words_found.append(word)
    return "Words found:", words_found.__len__(), " The words are:", words_found


english_dic=['sage', 'selection']
spanish_dic=['grupo', 'bien']


TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(df1["Reescribe aquí / Rewrite here"])

i=1

for rows in [x.lower() for x in df1["Reescribe aquí / Rewrite here"]]:

    if detect(rows)=='en':

        print(i, "-", rows, find_all_words(english_dic, rows), "Language of text:", detect(rows))

    elif detect(rows)=='es':

        print(i, "-", rows, find_all_words(spanish_dic, rows), "Language of text:", detect(rows))

    i += 1
```

Which prints:

```
1 - el grupo sage dijo que todo esta bien ('Words found:', 2, ' The words are:', ['grupo', 'bien']) Language of text: es
2 - sage group clarifies that the selection of vaccines is optimal ('Words found:', 2, ' The words are:', ['sage', 'selection']) Language of text: en
```

What I want is that, from the words from the predefined dictionary I created, a code which is able to to detect the synonyms from those words and return them as valid values.

For example, instead of "selection", it returns "choice" as a valid value for instance.

Comment: Does your predefined dictionary include all of the synonyms?  You will need to make a dict that maps each synonym to its "master", and then search your text for all of the words and synonyms.

Comment: No, I have just specific keywords on my predefined dictionary, but I wanted to automatically detect a synonym of those words and accept. I was thinking using something like: 

def get_synonyms_en(word):
    """Get the synomys of a word.
    Input:
        word: a string
    Output:
        synonyms: a list of words containing the synonyms of the input word

    """
    synonyms = []

    for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms.append(l.name())

    return synonyms

But I don't know exactly how to implement it into my actual code.

Comment: Well, software can't "detect" synonyms.  You would have to start with a dictionary and sort them into synonym bins.  You would then look up each word in your massive dictionary, and have it point redirect to your "master" synonym.  That is made much more difficult by the fact that many English words have very different meanings depending on context.